# How to temporarily save UIImage to Camera Roll

Tags: swift, uiimage, ios-camera, photokit, camera-roll

I know that I can save an UIImage to Camera Roll/Photo Album using the following code.

```swift
let image = UIImage(data: data) {
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
}
```

However, this does not provide for a way to know where that image is specifically stored as there is no direct path.

I was wondering if it is possible to save an image to camera roll, and then, later on, is it possible to delete that exact image using swift code alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is totally possible! However, you would need to use the PhotoKit framework for that. You can find the complete documentation for it [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit).

There is a nice sample project, that also shows how to [delete photos](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/browsing_and_modifying_photo_albums#3569959) (<- links directly to the deletion section) referenced from that documentation page.

To save the image in the first place, you would need to use the `PHAssetChangeRequest` instead of `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`. Specifically, there's [`PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phassetchangerequest/1624060-creationrequestforasset).

Keep in mind that you need to execute change requests (both for creation and deletion) from within a [`performChanges`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phphotolibrary/1620743-performchanges) call on the `PHPhotoLibrary`.

Btw. if you retrieve the image from somewhere and need to preserve the metadata (like Exif data), you should use [`PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImage(atFileURL:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phassetchangerequest/1624059-creationrequestforassetfromimage) to create the asset.

Hope this helps to get you started.